# Como posso encontrar dados de uma transmissão ao vivo do youtube?

Tags: android, youtube-api

Olá, estou tentando trazer uma transmissão ao vivo que é realizada por um endereço fixo no youtube por meio de uma api, utilizando `youtube.liveBroadcasts.bind`.
Porém para isso, preciso obter os seguintes dados:

id e part

que são para configurar a api.

alguém poderia me ajudar a encontrar?

obrigado